# ILRepack error with SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm trying to merge my VB .EXE with the SQLite.Interop.dll.  I can't use ILRepack on this DLL, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to load assembly D:\+ WORK\Test\ILRepack\4\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadOptionalHeaders(UInt16& subsystem, UInt16& dll_characteristics)
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage()
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImageFrom(Stream stream)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Stream stream, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at ILRepacking.ILRepack.ReadInputAssemblies()
   at ILRepacking.ILRepack.Repack()
   at ILRepacking.ILRepack.Main(String[] args)
```

I think it has something to do with Managed Assemblies.  Any idea which package I should include instead?

Answer (score 0):

Neither ILRepack nor ILMerge can work on native assemblies (which SQLite.Interop.dll is, i.e non-managed code), as they both operate on bytecode (IL) level.

You can either leave this library out of the merge, or (as I assume you'd like to include it) go the [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) way instead, which works fine with native assemblies.